# Android AlertDialog Multi Choice Items with customised items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Does anyone know how to customize items in AlertDialog when multi choice items are set with setMultiChoiceItems(...). I would like to change the text size for the items.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use Dialog.setContentView() to set the content of a dialog to be an arbitrary layout.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutId);
dialog.show();
```

Make yourself a layout file with a components that you want in it and call setContentView on your dialog, passing the name of your layout file.

If you are deadset on AlertDialog you can do something similar with builder.setView()

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutId, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutRoot));
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setView(layout);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: the question was about the multi choice part more than the layout. I'm looking for the same thing at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom AlertDialog where you can change the text size of any element. A simple generic example: http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-display-custom-dialog-and.html