# Redirect to another URL that contains page title like SO

Tags: url, model-view-controller

if i hit this url "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564547" then SO takes me to another url "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564547/android-alertdialog-multi-choice-items-with-customised-items".  My question is how to implements such a feature and how SO implements it?

What i think of is checking the url parameter id and fetching the title from database and redirecting to the URL. Any better option ?

Answer (score 0):

You need these steps:

1. Get the question ID from the URL, ignoring any title
2. Get the question from the database, using that ID
3. Compare the retrieved title with the supplied title, if any. Allow for SEO changes (space to dash and so on)
4. If no match, redirect to the correct URL; else continue.