# How to customize the Android Ringtone Picker Dialog?

Tags: android

I show a dialog for selecting one of the ring tones with the following code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
 intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE,"My customised Title");
 Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
 MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 1l);
 // Don't show 'Silent'
 intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
 intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, uri);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

It open a ringtone select dialog like below.

Now, Here you can see the fonts are too large, `i want to make it small`, so how can i do it ? How can i make it small.

[image]

Comment: You need to make a Custom Dialog.

Comment: Can i change font size with my above current code ? Is it possible ?

Comment: I think this is the only way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564547/android-alertdialog-multi-choice-items-with-customised-items

Comment: I can just advice you to get all the ringtones yourself , and make custom dialog yourself, this can be helpful while creating ListView for custom dailog http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/ I have no idea to change in the default dialog so suggesting the other way possible, I can not confirm that what you are asking is possible or not.

Comment: Another guess I can make is changing the Default font size from the device/emulator settings will also reduce the size.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting MKJParekh:

> You need to make a Custom Dialog.

Yes you need a custom `Dialog`, but keep in mind when talking about **"Custom Dialog"**, it doesn't mean that you can simply embed that Dialog with the above code to pick tones.

Since that is android-framework provided way of selecting ring tone, you don't need to query the tones, you don't need to make List in Dialog, you don't need to implement to select and pass data back to calling Activity. it is all built-in by android.

When making your own Custom Dialog, you have to do following tasks in your Activity/Dialog

- You need to query the data from android media
- You have to show that result in Dialog and ListView
- You have to make your own adapter and selection method
- Pass that data to calling Activity as Result

However customizing the android provided Dialog is impossible, its UI is dependent of theme, os and manufacturer.